# Why doesn't the read and write mode work?

Tags: python

```
handler = open('test.txt', 'a+')

for idx, line in enumerate(handler):
    print(idx, line.strip())
```

I want the 'read and write' file mode using 'a+', but, but it prints out nothing. If I change to 'r+', it prints:

```
0 a test
1 two test
```

My test.txt is below:

```
a test
two test
```

I want to open the file, and potentially append any new text to the end of the file. Why doesn't the 'a+' work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a file in `a` mode, the file cursor is positioned at the end, not the beginning. You need to seek to the beginning to read the file.

```
handler = open('test.txt', 'a+')
handler.seek(0)
for idx, line in enumerate(handler):
    print(idx, line.strip())
```